# Serial port disconnected before being closed

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

I use `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` to manage RS232 communication without any problem. However, more and more devices propose RS232 communication throw an USB connector which imply an emulated serial port on the PC.
My concern is when the device is turned off, the serial port is no longer available on the PC, and when I use the `Close()` function to release the communication, I get an exception that I'm not able to catch by any `try...catch`, and so the full application close (no just in time recover).
Checking step by step what happen it seems the serial port resource is disposed when I try to close it and that causes the failure.

Is there a way to know if the port is still available or catch the exception ?

I've also tried to list again available ports with `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()` just before calling the `Close()` function, but the port is still listed.

Thanks

Comment: These articles may be helpful. [DeviceWatcher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher?view=winrt-19041), [Monitor USB drives and retrieve device Info using a DeviceWatcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24944865/9014308), [Detect serial port insertion/removal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4199083/9014308)

Comment: Hi @kunif, finally I used the last proposal, triggering port removal allows me to avoid calling `Close()` method. Thank you.